# How to add a line break with function using JS, HTML

Tags: javascript, html

It's going to be used in app for FirefoxOS. Being tested with WebIDE Firefoxos 2.2

```
<p>
    <input type="text" align="right" id="screen" name="kijelzo"/>               
    <button onclick="add()" name="add" >Add</button>
    <button onclick="clear()" name="add" >Clear</button>
</p>
<h1 id="stuff">
</h1>
<script>
    function add(){                                                        
        var plusz=document.getElementById('screen').value;
        var element=document.getElementById('stuff');
        element.innerHTML=element.innerHTML+plusz;
        // i'd like to have a linebreak after every single added element.
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `element.innerHTML=element.innerHTML+ "<br>" + plusz;` ?

Comment: Add a + "\n" or if you need html add a +"<br/>"

Comment: Why don't you use CSS?

Comment: I'm planning to, but this is my very first program with these languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add line breaks in HTML with the `<br>` tag.

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "<br />" + plusz;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/79fa8h1t/2/ (I don't need the points, I just like to provide an example)